# Как организовать хранение такой связи данных?

Tags: bootstrap, vb.net, структуры-данных, поиск-библиотек, intellisense

Сразу скажу, что вопрос может показаться странным и кому то не нужным, но тем не менее есть такая задача:

У нас есть набор элементов `HTML` и набор `CSS` классов из `Bootstrap` например 3.0

У нас так же есть правила при которых, определенные элементы сочетаются с определенными классами, а так же есть связи по уровням вложенности элементов друг в друга.

А так же есть отношения между классами по уровню обязательности, например с кнопками, мы знаем что минимум для кнопки нужен класс `btn` но так же есть класс декоратор-стилизатор `btn-primary` который необязателен но возможен.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

Вопрос:

1) Как организовать хранение набора таких связей, база типа SQL или NoSQL, XSD или что то иное?

2) Откуда спарсить подобную информацию по связям, или может подобное уже реализовано, например в плагинах для IDE для организации intellisense?
Или может есть какие то другие библиотеки?

Что посоветуете?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду правила в рамках вашей задачи либо правила вообще?

Comment: @becouse Вроде из этой фразы должно быть понятно, "но тем не менее есть такая задача", конечно же в рамках данной задачи.

Comment: Какая используется IDE?

Comment: @becouse А причем тут IDE? Речь о программировании, о работе с такими данными. Наверное стоит указать ЯП, сейчас добавлю. Речь о .NET и Pyhon например.

Comment: Тогда это граф ориентированый. Как его хранить? Можно в виде ассоциативного массива, можно списком ребер.

Comment: @becouse ) И как вы себе представляете серьезное приложение которое к массиву будет обращаться и каким то чудом доставать нужные значения без нормального интерфейса поиска? Может тогда это графовые базы данных? Тогда вопросик, граф это единственный вариант?

Comment: А как из текста понять, что вы хотите сделать? По постановке задачи понятно, что вас интересует интеллектуальная подстановка. Нарисуйте кусок зависимостей и у вас будет два варианта: дерево или граф. Дерево хранить просто, хоть в XML, граф сложнее. Насколько я понимаю вы ожидаете поведения в стиле "выдай мне все допустимые атрибуты и классы для заданного класса"? Тогда это обычная иерархия (дерево) по типу любого дерева классов.